# WSL, Docker + Python logger -- IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running Docker for Windows (Version 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507))

Calling a behave application (python testing framework) using docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    behave:
        build:
            context: .
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: test
            DB_DATABASE: testdb
        volumes:
            - ".:/app"
        command:
            - bash
            - run_test.sh
            - docker
            - --capture
            - --stop
            - ${FEATURE:-feature}/
            - ${TAGS}
        network_mode: host
```

The Dockerfile is pretty vanilla:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update       \
    && apt-get -y upgrade       \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential software-properties-common curl bzip2 libfreetype6 libfontconfig wget libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN cd /usr/local/share \
    && wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    && tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
    && ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs \
    && ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs \
    && ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
RUN apt-get -y install python python-dev python-setuptools python-pycurl python-tz python-pymongo python-cffi python-openssl python-pip
ADD . /app
RUN cd /app \
    && apt-get -y install python-httplib2 \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
WORKDIR /app
ENV HOME=/app
```

In the behave app, I use the standard python logging as such:

```
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(BASEDIR + "logs/" + name + ".log", mode='w')
fileHandler.setLevel(flevel)
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

This runs fine in linux directly.  And, it also runs fine in WSL directly (i.e. not via docker).

The failure is:

```
File "/app/testlib/log_helpers/__init__.py", line 55, in get_dual_logger
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(BASEDIR + "logs/" + name + ".log", mode='a')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 913, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 944, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/logs/behave.log'
```

To try and see if there was anything strange, I added a simple print statement in `/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py` before it opens the file.  As my test starts, it prints:

```
Opening /app/logs/behave.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave.log with: a
```

before failing (so the first open works, the second fails).

If I update my logger to always write to a unique file with code like this:

```
while os.path.exists(BASEDIR + "logs/" + name + ".log"):
    name += "_"
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(BASEDIR + "logs/" + name + ".log", mode='a')
...
```

then it works fine.

```
Opening /app/logs/behave.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave_.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave__.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave___.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave____.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave_____.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave______.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave_______.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave________.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave_________.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave__________.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave___________.log with: a
Opening /app/logs/behave____________.log with: a
```

So, the core of the problem is the standard library python command (in logger.py):

`stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)`

Whether I use mode of "w" or "a", the second time a log file is opened by python inside a docker container running on WSL, this fails.

Has anybody ever seen anything like this in WSL?  Any workaround?

Seems very, very specific to my use-case, not sure if this is known or not